# What does "inter alia" in "difference-indifference" testing?

Tags: difference-in-difference

today my paper get rejected due to this reason when I used the Difference-in-Difference as my methodology

> In addition, it would need to address concerns about causal estimates
> as there are a number of assumptions which are unaddressed. These
> include, **inter alia**, anticipation effects and omitted confounders.

I am wondering what does "inter alia" mean here, or it just mean that I need to address "anticipation effects" and "omitted cofounders" problem in my research?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It [means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inter%20alia) "among other things". Its not an economics term, its standard English. It is somewhat pretentious, having been borrowed from Latin.

Can I suggest that next time you don't understand a word or phrase you try Google first?

Comment: I don’t think the use of Latin is always pretentious, ceteris paribus.